# How to compare between current branch to the beginning when it's created in git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-diff

I create a new branch `bugfix/fixing-something` from the `master` branch.

After that I made those actions:
commit, commit, push, commit, push, create pr, merge this or to master, commit (continue on this branch), commit, push, create pr, merge to the master, commit and push.

Now I want to see the diff between this current branch to the beginning when I open the branch.

Is it possible to do with vscode or git command? if so which command will do this diff?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```sh
git diff bugfix/fixing-something $(git merge-base --fork-point bugfix/fixing-something master)
```

This compares the tip of the `bugfix/fixing-something` branch with the first common parent between `bugfix/fixing-something` and `master`, aka the [*fork point*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#_discussion_on_fork_point_mode).

Comment: Be careful: this fork point information is only saved for a limited amount of time (by default it starts to expire after 90 days). (This is noted in the link you gave, but some may not click on that or understand the caveat.)